# Doctrine repository returns empty resultset

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

Having a real problem with a [Doctrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29) repository.

It returns an empty resultset, even using the findAll() method. There are entries in the table, and the generated SQL works perfectly. Other repositories work fine. There are no error message/exceptions - just an empty resultset.

Tearing my hair out.

Using Doctrine 2.1.6

Anyone have any pointers of where to start looking?

The entity definition is at http://pastie.org/private/o4lbdxsnjq1vogkeburbaq3d

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a legitimate question to ask?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what is wrong? Try to remove repositoryClass attribute and check it with the default repository.

Comment: meze - I have tried that, it doesn't make a difference. This is why I am having the problems, Doctrine is not throwing any errors/exceptions, and the generated SQL works. It is not transparent and I asked in case others have had similar problems and could help.

Comment: That can be cache, doctrine uses a different database...

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Entities use the EntityRepository until you declare your own repositories. If you declare you own Repository, you first may start check if you extend your repository from the original EntityRepository.

I found [this blog post](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/the_power_of_doctrine_2s_custom_repositories_and_native_queries), was very helpful to me back in those days :)

You may also want to check [Doctrine API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html).

**Second**

I know that the `findAll()` method does not throw any exception until you check and create one.

For example:

```
$exm = $this->em->getRepository('myRepo')->findAll();
if(!$exm)   
    throw new \Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
```

P.S: I might be wrong. However I've used this style for years and I'm happy with it. If I am wrong, i would be happy to learn the best way. So correct me please!

Comment: Both links are not working anymore. I have the same issue and my repository extends ServiceEntityRepository. Symfony 5.1.5, Doctrine 2.1.2